# Como borrar el Footer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Deseamos eliminar el Footer que esta en la página de https://bioconstruccion.com.mx/ pero lamentablemente no podemos eliminarlo, no encontramos desde donde está puesto o si lo insertaron directamente por código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Puedes comentar en las páginas la función get_footer() que generalmente es la encargada de insertar el footer, y de ese modo debería dejar de mostrarse. Otra opción es ocultarla/mostrarla en función del idioma, el cual se consulta con if (get_locale()=="es-ES"){ /*código a ejecutar */ }.

Answer (score 0):

¿Quieres borrar todo el footer, o nada mas la leyenda de por quien viene desarrollado?, por que si es eliminar todo el **`footer`** o buscar si lo metieron directo, puedes entrar a la siguiente ruta:

```
wp-content / themes / theguem (Este es el nombre de tu tema) / templates / footer
```

y  de ahi puedes buscar el texto del **copyright** si es que lo metieron directo o borrar el pedazo de código que te esta mostrando el **`footer`**.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, si la idea es quitar todo el Footer, ¿pero no habrá problema con el tema padre o así?

Comment: Estamos trabajando con el Plugin polylang para tener el sitio en dos idiomas pero el footer carga igual para ambos

Comment: Tienes que agregar un plugin para poder traducir el footer y widgets lo instalas y tienes que duplicar el footer en tus widgets para que cuando cambies a ingles o español te muestre el footer con el idioma seleccionado.

El plugin te funciona si el footer lo cargas desde los widgets de tu tema:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

Comment: Ok muchas gracias javoreyesmx, voy a probarlo y veré qué tal me va. Pero al parecer el footer está desde código. No como un Widget y al momento de quitar el archivo footer de la carpeta del sitio se borran algunos formatos de arriba, así que no se que hacer.